# How to find the load directory of keras_nlp model tokenizer?

Tags: python, keras

I'm new to `keras_nlp`. I failed in running the following code. The following code automatically download the file from [url](https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-nlp/models/deberta_v3_base_en/v1/vocab.spm).

```
preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.DebertaV3Preprocessor.from_preset(
    preset=CFG.preset, # Name of the model
    sequence_length=CFG.sequence_length, # Max sequence length, will be padded if shorter
)
```

The failure reason is that my server is blocked from the outer urls so that I have to manually download it to my PC and upload it to the server. Now I download the file but I don't know where I shall put it. I tried to find it in the src file but I failed.

What is the directory where keras_nlp is searching for the tokenizer file?

Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: I found `vocab.spm` in code with `from_preset()` in line with [get_file()](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-nlp/blob/1144b4570224ddaa325d64f4769698b60ce26ade/keras_nlp/tokenizers/sentence_piece_tokenizer.py#L264) which uses `cache_subdir=os.path.join("models", preset)` and this suggest that you may have it in `models/name_of_your models` (value from `CFG.preset`). You may have to check source code for `keras.utils.get_file()` to see if it create `model` in some special folder,.

Comment: Other idea: run code on computer which has access to Internet and check where it installs this file. You may need to use some tool to seach folder `models/name_of_your models`. On Linux you could use command `find`